# Are these ordinals cardinals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Consider $\omega_2 \times \omega$ and $\omega \times \omega_2$ with ordinal arithmetic.

Then $| \omega_2  \times \omega | =\omega_2$

and $| \omega \times \omega_2 | =\omega_2$

Does this imply that neither  $\omega_2 \times \omega$ nor $\omega \times \omega_2$ are cardinals??

Comment: How would this imply that?

Comment: @Andres because both have cardinality $\omega_2$ but are not equal to $\omega_2$. So they would be  ordinals which fall between $\omega_2$ and $\omega_3$ and therefore not cardinals.

Comment: Both have cardinality $\omega_2$, not "greater than". And why are they not equal to $\omega_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the inductive definitions of ordinal multiplication:

$$\begin{align}
&\alpha\cdot0=0\\
&\alpha\cdot(\beta+1)=\alpha\cdot\beta+\alpha\\
&\alpha\cdot\delta=\sup\{\alpha\cdot\gamma\mid\gamma<\delta\},\ \delta\text{ is a limit ordinal}
\end{align}$$

Since $\omega$ and $\omega_2$ are certainly limit ordinals, we have that: $\omega_2\cdot\omega=\sup\{\omega_2\cdot n\mid n<\omega\}$, and since $\alpha\cdot2=\alpha+\alpha>\alpha$, whenever $\alpha>0$, we have that indeed $\omega_2\cdot\omega>\omega_2$ ***as ordinals***.

On the other hand, $\omega\cdot\omega_2=\sup\{\omega\cdot\gamma\mid\gamma<\omega_2\}$. This is a supremum of $\omega_2$ ordinals, and we can show that each of those (of the $\omega\cdot\gamma$'s) has size $\leq\aleph_1$. Therefore $\omega\cdot\omega_2=\omega_2$, which is in fact a cardinal.